# Push Notifications are not properly received by android device

Tags: android, push-notification

I am use push notification in android. I get every time response like below.

```
MulticastResult(multicast_id=5497010412827061205,total=1,success=1,failure=0,canonical_ids=0,results: [[ messageId=0:1394436372955612%dea36ef2fbeed099 ]]
```

I get every time response like above. I get messageId in response. Means that message is deliver by GCM server is fine. But Sometime I got push notification in device and sometime not.

What is the reason behind this ?

Comment: What do you mean by "But Sometime I got push notification in device and sometime not"?

Comment: Means But Sometime I got push notification in device and sometime not get in device.

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue. The issue got solved when i disconnected the network and connected it again. Like turning OFF the mobile network and turning it ON solved it for me.